# Не работает .htaccess Джино

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Добрый день. Купил домен и хостинг у хостера Джино. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, не пашет .htaccess. Тех. поддержка молчит, на локалке все отрабатывало прекрасно. У каждого хостера свои правила по настройке этого файла? Это просто моя первая покупка платного хостинга.

Вот содержимое файла:

```
php_flag session.use_only_cookies on
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT]
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, эта опция поможет:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

[Jino PHP FAQ](https://www.jino.ru/help/faq/php/)